# How to reduce amap Array.prototype.some() calls?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, optimization, rxjs

I have a service managing data fetched from a SocketIO API such as

```
export class DataService {
  private data: SomeData[];

  // ...
  
  getData(): Observable<SomeData[]> {
    // distinctUntilChanged was used to limit Observable to only emits when data changes
    // but it does not seem to change much things...
    return this.data.pipe(distinctUntilChanged());
  }
 
  // ...
}
```

and a component calling this service to do

```
this.banana$ = combineLatest([
  someFnToRequestANetworkObject(),
  DataService.getData()
]).pipe(
  map(([network, data]) => network && data.some(_data=> _data.ip === network.ip))
);
```

The thing is that each time one of the Observable handled within `combineLatest` gets emitted, I get to call `Array.prototype.some()` function. Which I don't want to.

How could I optimize this code so that I don't call `some` too often ?

Comment: if it does need to be called everytime, `combineLatest ` is not the right operator

Comment: What would you rather use then ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note about `distinctUntilChanged()` operator is it affects only the subscription. So the operators between the source observable and the subscription are still run. As workaround you could manually check if `data` has changed between emissions. Try the following

```js
let oldData: any;
this.banana$ = combineLatest([
  someFnToRequestANetworkObject(),
  DataService.getData()
]).pipe(
  map(([network, data]) => {
    if (!oldData || oldData !== data) {
      oldData = data;
      return (network && data.some(_data=> _data.ip === network.ip));
    }
    return false; // <-- return what you wish when `data` hasn't changed
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your hunch about `distinctUntilChanged` not working is correct.
By default, this operator uses an equality check to determine if two values are the same.
However, this will (in most cases) not work properly if the objects being compared aren't simple scalar values like numbers or booleans.

As it turns out, [you can provide your own comparator function](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/distinctUntilChanged) as the first argument to `distinctUntilChanged`.
This will be called on "successive" elements to determine if the new element is different from the most recent one.

The exact definition of this comparator function depends on what your `SomeData` class/interface looks like, along with what it means for an array of `SomeData` inhabitants to be the same as another one.
But, as an example, let's say that `SomeData` looks like this:

```
interface SomeData {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

and that `SomeData` inhabitants are the same if they have the same `id`.
Furthermore, let's suppose that two *arrays* of `SomeData`s are the same if they contain exactly the same `SomeData` elements.
Then our comparator function might look like:

```
function eqSomeDataArrays(sds1: SomeData[], sds2: SomeData[]): boolean {
  // Two arrays of `SomeData` inhabitants are the same if...
         // ...they contain the same number of elements...
  return sds1.length === sds2.length
         // ...which are "element-wise", the same (i.e. have the same `id`)
      && sds1.every((sd1, i) => sd1.id === sds2[i].id)
}
```

To round it all out, your `getData` method would now look like:

```
getData(): Observable<SomeData[]> {
  return this.data.pipe(distinctUntilChanged(eqSomeDataArrays));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the pipe, after map call, you could use shareReplay(1)

```
this.banana$ = combineLatest([
  someFnToRequestANetworkObject(),
  DataService.getData()])
.pipe(
  map(([network, data]) => network && data.some(_data=> _data.ip === network.ip)),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```